# Adding PHP file to wordpress - Header() already sent

Tags: php, wordpress, gd

Few days ago i was looking for way to use my custom php on wordpress site and i found answer here: [How to add a php page to Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress). 
Tried few examples and it worked well for each of them. But then i wanted to go further and use PHP image processing in wordpress page added like that. It **works on normal php site (using JUST this code), but when i try to use it in worpress** i get error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyeleven\header.php:13) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyeleven\mynewsite.php on line 26
```

My code i am trying to use is:

```
<?php
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('image2.jpg');

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100); //putting one image on top of other

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Well i know the problem is i am trying to send header here, but i dont know how to solve it.
I tried moving this header to top of the file, but then whole worpress site don't load.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
get_header(); //<-- part of wordpress template, cant get rid of it, cuz it ruins whole site look.
```

So looks like get_header(); is somehow "problem" here.
Tried using ob_start(), flush, clean etc, but then i get the image i want, without worpress site loading. I ran out of options, and non of these solved my problem.

My question is: How to send this header to make it work, cuz without it i see some weird symbols instead of png image (like i would open png image with notepad)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found solution to this. Posting answer as it might be useful for someone else in the future.

So I will be using simple words, which made me understand this.
`header('Content-Type: image/png');` makes whole site to be "treated as image". So when I even found the place where to put my header in WordPress files, it still didn't show any result at all. To solve this problem, just create another file called `image.php` and put the PHP GD code there.

```
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('image2.jpg');
imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 9, 0, 0, 181, 180, 100); //putting one image on top of other
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Of course in `<?php ?>` tags, and in WordPress page, where you want display it use `<img src = "image.php">`. This will get rid of all errors with headers, and also will display already created image by this PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem when i had a space/newline after the closing php tag "?>" I removed it from all of my files and it worked for me. Pretty weird but it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case for me. Well, there is no space/newline in my files, but it would be impossible to search trough all the wordpress files.