# The WordPress function the_title() is showing blank

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to display a post on my homepage. `<?php the_title(); ?>` is returning blank.

Source: [idolizeonline.com](http://idolizeonline.com) ([NSFW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NSFW#Adjective) link)

-- If you hover over the thumbnails, the title and excerpt of the post should appear over the image (excerpt is title is not).

```
<?php if(!of_get_option('ttrust_open_project_single')) : ?>

    <div class="project small ajx <?php echo $p; ?>" id="project-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ></a>

        <a href="#<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail($project_thumb_size, array('class' => 'thumb', 'alt' => ''.get_the_title().'', 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'')); ?></a>
        <span class="title">
            <div>
                <span id="theTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                <span id="theExcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="project small <?php echo $p; ?>" id="project-<?php echo $post->post_name;?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ></a>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail($project_thumb_size, array('class' => 'thumb', 'alt' => ''.get_the_title().'', 'title' => ''.get_the_title().'')); ?></a>
        <span class="title">
            <div>
                <span id="theTitle"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                <span id="theExcerpt"><?php the_excerpt() ?></span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Does the call to `the_exerpt()` work?

Comment: Did you try get_the_title ? Does that return anything? Look at this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title

Comment: @andrewsi, it's `the_excerpt()`.

Comment: @SpencerCameron - this is what happens when I'm under-caffeinated. Though I'd still like to know if it works :)

Comment: I figured it was a typo. :) I don't think it will, though. His template is missing an integral piece needed by the template tag system. See my answer below.

Comment: @andrewsi the call to `the_excerpt()` does work

Comment: What file is this in?

Comment: What do you mean by *"excerpt is title is not"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: Strongly related: [Solomon Closson's answer to *How can I add a PHP page to WordPress?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-can-i-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress/39800534#39800534) (that is, `get_header();` will include "Page not found" (instead of the page title) and `the_title();` is blank, with a possible common cause).

Answer (score 3):

Put the following code at the top of your file:

`<?php if( have_posts() ) the_post(); ?>`

**See:** [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: I added this above `<?php if(!of_get_option('ttrust_open_project_single')) : ?>` and it didn't work

Comment: Perhaps there is no valid post to display? Put this at the top of your file temporarily: `<?php if( ! have_posts() ) echo 'No valid posts'; ?>` If you see **No valid posts** output, you've got other problems.

Comment: I added the code, it didn't apear. I'm lost as to why `the_excerpt()` works and not `the_title()`

Comment: What if it is a *'[page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVqzKAUsM68&t=1h32m50s)'*, not a *'post'*?

Answer (score 3):

I am still unsure what exactly was the issue, but replacing `the_title();` with `<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `page.php` file. Do you have all these things included in that file?

```
global $post;global $wpdb;
// Your header goes here

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="your_main_div_to_display_content">
// Your title goes here
<?php the_title();?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

// Your footer goes here
```

Comment: What if it is WordPress *'pages'* (static), not WordPress *'posts'* (blog posts)?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and in my case I was using `$post` for another purpose, which was conflicting and causing `the_title()` to display blank.

Comment: What purpose? Form submit?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue while developing a WordPress theme. WordPress has some declared variables being declared globally, like `$post`, `$posts`, `Post` and so on, if you are coding a WordPress plugin or theme, you need to make sure you treat those variable names like a reserved word. This is one of the errors you can encounter if you don't.