# How to customise a wordpress theme so it has a login section

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add my own webpages to a wordpress theme that are totally independent of the theme.
I have seen how to do something like this here using adam's answer

[How to add a PHP page to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress)

However how would i go about  making certain pages require a login? If the user is logged it it says
"hi joe, go to your area" and if you arent logged in it says "login here"

The login area can look like a separate section and just be independent php pages. However in the existing pages where would I check login status? I would store this in a session variable probably

I assume this type of thing would be theme dependent but I'm just investigating if it is possible.
I am guessing I would have to modify the header file to show a specific message based on session variables.

If anyone has an idea for a better approach or a plugin that does this that would be mucch appreciated

Thanks as ever for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try at your custom page-

```
 <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by jitendra you can use wordpress function is_user_loggeed_in to check if user is logged in or not. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

and you can use wp_login_form to show login form
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form

so

```
 <?php
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      // your content here  
 } else {
       wp_login_form(); 
 }
 ?>
```