# Loading a native html page on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

So I made a pure html page, and I need to import it to a Wordpress environment which I have formated correctly. Is there a way I can display the page natively without the need to make it a small snippet. In other words can I display the html document normally and fully through Wordpress with no interference from Wordpress's theme engine.

Comment: You could set it up as a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) and then create a new page and assign it that template. However, you're going to need to change it to `.php` and you will need to add some Wordpress calls in order to get the header/footer/sidebar etc. into this page. If it's completely standalone(has it's own CSS, Javascript, etc.), then you don't need to do any of that but you'd still need to rename it to `.php` and add the template syntax in order for Wordpress to recognize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a page through the Wordpress dashboard with, for example, a slug of "mypage", you can then override the template that is used to display the page by creating a file in the theme folder called `page-mypage.php`.

You can then just add your own HTML to that template and it will only affect that one page. Don't forget that you'll need to also import the CSS and and Javascript files that you use (and possibly modify the file paths so that they can still be found). Let me know if you need assistance with that.