# How to add a PHP page with GET variables in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html, get

Having trouble figuring out if its possible to pass GET variables for a PHP page in Wordpress.
The link to the below SO question describes how to add custom PHP pages to Wordpress, but how to pass GET variables along ?

[How to add a PHP page to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress)

[image]

Comment: Could you develop your question and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Consider that am selling products online, so for each product I need the template to similar, but specifications of the product to be different. So i thought it would be good if I put templates as told in the SO question i mentioned and i will pass the product id via a GET variable.

Comment: @Andytheandroid Please stay strictly professional on SO and avoid swears and insults.

Answer (score 0):

Create your page under let's say `example.com/mypage`
Then send a GET request with myvariable to it

```
example.com/mypage?myvariable=1
```

Comment: @Andytheandroid you are disrespectful. Bye now