# How Can I add Email Verification Functions For WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add Email verification procedure when user registers in WooCommerce. WordPress then emails a verification link to user's email. If link is clicked, it then activates the user's account. How would I do that?

Comment: But there is a problem in this plugin not adding user in wordpress.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant to write code for you. You have to give very specific details about what the problem is. Code. Screenshots. Expected and actual results. A good question should rarely be 1 sentence.

Comment: No I can't because you haven't provided enough detail. Without details it's VERY hard to answer your question because we can't find the answer until you give details.

Comment: This is my site http://www.thesincitystore.com/my-account/ you can register and check the error.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not going to register. You need to take the time to provide more details. :) once you do that I would be more then happy to look at your question and see if I have a solution for you.

Comment: But site is not my its my client so can't give details . thank you Charlie for reply my Question.

Comment: you do not need to do download plugin from Github its may be the problem with your download just go directly to this link to download plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-confirmation-email/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have used the code provided by [Amit Kayshap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3534777/amit-kashyap) and refined it to include extra checks and functions like automatically logging a user in after their account has been activated, resulting in a much smoother user experience.

**Update:** Unlike the original code, this one will not require any existing user to confirm their email address as well.

Like the code I based it upon, it is designed to run on a WordPress installation running WooCommerce. It also works if you have disabled the standard WordPress registration page.

You'll need an empty page with the URL `yoursite.com/verify/` that builds on a template that contains `<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>` within its content container. It'll replace the `/sign-in/` destination from the original code and will handle almost all messages created by this code.

Next, add this code to your theme's functions.php:

```
function wc_registration_redirect( $redirect_to ) {     // prevents the user from logging in automatically after registering their account
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect( '/verify/?n=1');                       // redirects to a confirmation message
    exit;
}

function wp_authenticate_user( $userdata ) {            // when the user logs in, checks whether their email is verified
    $has_activation_status = get_user_meta($userdata->ID, 'is_activated', false);
    if ($has_activation_status) {                           // checks if this is an older account without activation status; skips the rest of the function if it is
        $isActivated = get_user_meta($userdata->ID, 'is_activated', true);
        if ( !$isActivated ) {
            my_user_register( $userdata->ID );              // resends the activation mail if the account is not activated
            $userdata = new WP_Error(
                'my_theme_confirmation_error',
                __( '<strong>Error:</strong> Your account has to be activated before you can login. Please click the link in the activation email that has been sent to you.<br /> If you do not receive the activation email within a few minutes, check your spam folder or <a href="/verify/?u='.$userdata->ID.'">click here to resend it</a>.' )
            );
        }
    }
    return $userdata;
}

function my_user_register($user_id) {               // when a user registers, sends them an email to verify their account
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);                                            // gets user data
    $code = md5(time());                                                            // creates md5 code to verify later
    $string = array('id'=>$user_id, 'code'=>$code);                                 // makes it into a code to send it to user via email
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'is_activated', 0);                                  // creates activation code and activation status in the database
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'activationcode', $code);
    $url = get_site_url(). '/verify/?p=' .base64_encode( serialize($string));       // creates the activation url
    $html = ( 'Please click <a href="'.$url.'">here</a> to verify your email address and complete the registration process.' ); // This is the html template for your email message body
    wc_mail($user_info->user_email, __( 'Activate your Account' ), $html);          // sends the email to the user
}

function my_init(){                                 // handles all this verification stuff
    if(isset($_GET['p'])){                                                  // If accessed via an authentification link
        $data = unserialize(base64_decode($_GET['p']));
        $code = get_user_meta($data['id'], 'activationcode', true);
        $isActivated = get_user_meta($data['id'], 'is_activated', true);    // checks if the account has already been activated. We're doing this to prevent someone from logging in with an outdated confirmation link
        if( $isActivated ) {                                                // generates an error message if the account was already active
            wc_add_notice( __( 'This account has already been activated. Please log in with your username and password.' ), 'error' );
        }
        else {
            if($code == $data['code']){                                     // checks whether the decoded code given is the same as the one in the data base
                update_user_meta($data['id'], 'is_activated', 1);           // updates the database upon successful activation
                $user_id = $data['id'];                                     // logs the user in
                $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
                if( $user ) {
                    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
                    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
                    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login, $user );
                }
                wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Success:</strong> Your account has been activated! You have been logged in and can now use the site to its full extent.' ), 'notice' );
            } else {
                wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Error:</strong> Account activation failed. Please try again in a few minutes or <a href="/verify/?u='.$userdata->ID.'">resend the activation email</a>.<br />Please note that any activation links previously sent lose their validity as soon as a new activation email gets sent.<br />If the verification fails repeatedly, please contact our administrator.' ), 'error' );
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET['u'])){                                          // If resending confirmation mail
        my_user_register($_GET['u']);
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your activation email has been resent. Please check your email and your spam folder.' ), 'notice' );
    }
    if(isset($_GET['n'])){                                          // If account has been freshly created
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Thank you for creating your account. You will need to confirm your email address in order to activate your account. An email containing the activation link has been sent to your email address. If the email does not arrive within a few minutes, check your spam folder.' ), 'notice' );
    }
}

// the hooks to make it all work
add_action( 'init', 'my_init' );
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'wc_registration_redirect');
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'wp_authenticate_user',10,2);
add_action('user_register', 'my_user_register',10,2);
```

If you are running a multilingual site, you can make the code translation-ready very easily. Just change the text strings like this: `__( 'Text you want to translate', 'your-theme' )` This allows translation plugins like WPML to add the string to a translation table in the `your-theme` text domain.

Note that any string containing a variable like `.$url.` will generate a new string every time a different user activates its function. To circumvent this (and prevent string spamming into your database), we can translate them directly in the code:

```
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='de'){
    wc_add_notice( __( 'German error message' ), 'error' );
} else {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'English error message' ), 'error' );
}
```

In this example, the german message will be output if the user's language code is detected as `de` (Also works if it is a variation like `de_DE_formal`), else it will output the english message.

*Edit:* I updated the code to not require an existing user to retroactively confirm their email address.

Comment: This works great but took me a while to figure out the "an empty page that builds on a template" thing. It makes perfect sense after I found the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2810723/1358863

Comment: I have 2 registration options on my WC shop: usual and Facebook. Will this code affect users who register with Facebook?

Comment: @DemuriCelidze This code hooks into the WordPress core with `user_register`, `init` and `wp_authenticate_user` and into WooCommerce with `woocommerce_registration_redirect`, so unless your Facebook registration hooks into the WooCommerce process instead of directly into the WordPress core, the code probably won't work with the Facebook registration.

Comment: There is a small security issue in the code: anybody can deactivate any account by simply following a link like /?u=1. So need to check if the user is already activated, for example on line 58. I submitted an edit.