# How do I create a page template which takes PHP code in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, containers

The following is the code I have used for creating a template for a particular page of my website. Since, it's a pre-conference and an independent event, I need to design this page slightly different from what I have used for the home page.

So, I have copied the page.php and tried to modify the template.

I want:

1. I need to use the PHP code in the page in the WordPress page (because I need to do some query from my database and print it in the current page).
2. The left sidebar should be the navigation menu (custom).

   Maybe this is the rough:

   [image]

   ```
   <?php
       /**
        * Template Name:theme-meeting-template
        * This template will only display the content you entered in the page editor
        */
   ?>

   <?php
       /**
        * The template for displaying all pages.
        *
        * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
        * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
        * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
        * different template.
        *
        * @package panoramic
        */
   ?>

   <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

   <head>
       <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
       <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

       <?php wp_head(); ?>

       <div class="theme-head">
           <h1> The Fourth DAE-BRNS Theme Meeting on
                Generation and use of Covariance
                Matrices in the Applications of Nuclear Data</h1>

           <h2> December 09-13, 2017 </h2>
           <h2> Manipal University, Manipal, India </h2>
       </div>

       <div class="hor-nav" style="color: red; margin-top:20px; display: block">
           <ul>
               <li >
                   <a href="http://iclaa2017.com/test-template/">
                   home
                   </a>
               </li>
               <li >
                   <a href="#meetings">
                   Meetings </a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </head>

   <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
       <?php
           get_sidebar();
       ?>

       <div id="content" class="site-content site-container" >

           <?php if ( ! is_front_page() ) : ?>

               <?php if ( function_exists( 'bcn_display' ) ) : ?>
               <div class="breadcrumbs">
                   <?php bcn_display(); ?>
               </div>
               <?php endif; ?>

           <?php endif; ?>

           <div id="primary" class="content-area">

               <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                   <?php get_template_part( 'library/template-parts/page-title' ); ?>

                   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                       <?php get_template_part( 'library/template-parts/content', 'page' ); ?>

                       <?php
                           // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                           if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                               comments_template();
                           endif;
                       ?>

                   <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

               </main><!-- #main -->
           </div><!-- #primary -->

       <?php get_footer(); ?>
   ```

Kindly [click here for the output](http://iclaa2017.com/test-template/).

Comment: Remove head tag and body tag from template and use default header function in your custom template.

Comment: this didnt help me @AshPatel