# Populating a WordPress Page with posts from a Category or Tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress for my science journalism blog and I would like to add a page that contains a subset of the blog posts. For example, having a page populated by a certain category (i.e. review articles) or tags (i.e. physics).

There seems to be a way to do this by making [a new php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress), but I am not sure how to get to a blank template to add the code base.

Alternatively, I would prefer having a way to do this without having to mess with the code at all. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happens automatically with WordPress; read the docs:

> When a viewer clicks on a link to one of the Categories on your site,
>   he or she is taken to a page listing the Posts in that particular
>   Category in chronological order, from newest Posts at the top to
>   oldest at the bottom.

Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

You *don't have to* make a category or tag template page, but you can if you want to. This is theme-dependent; your theme may already have different archive page templates.

The URL for a category or tag archive page will be:

> example.net/category_base/category_name
>
> example.net/tag_base/tag_name

Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Category_base_and_Tag_base

Go to Appearance>Settings>Reading to set number of posts per page and either excerpt or full post.

Comment: This is the answer. Now Sarah will go to Appearance > Menus. Toggle "Screen Options" in the upper right corner of the page, click the check box next to Categories. Now that will be an option to add to your menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get at a category by going to http://example.com/category/mycategory

And to tags by visiting http://example.com/tag/mytag

You should be able to add categories to the main menu, and add tag pages via a custom link OR use a tag cloud?

Hope this helps.