# PHP in wordpress environment

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written all my codes with sublime text and Xampp, now I want to create a php site online and I am using wordpress which is not a php editor, but I learnt that I can manipulate my template files to work with php and also write php codes with a plugin in the wordpress page editor.

Now I have my registration code written and perfected with Xammp already, my signup.php code contains a mysql connection code and location code. I opened my template editor and edited my archive.php file to my signup.php code and also changed the template name to signup.php

Comment: Wordpress is written in php, so yeah, you can use php in wordpress templates. But what is your question?

Comment: It's best to provide code snippets for better response. Be clear about your question. Posts with out a clear question usually won't get good response.

Comment: K, my registration page is www.example.com/register  i have my template file archive.php changed to signup.php, now  i want to set my form action to that signup.php i created, will it work fine.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress

Comment: The link doesnt help, what i just need is how to link my form action to the template file (signup.php) i edited with the template editor..