# How can I add some posts in the homepage and have a blog page as well?

Tags: wordpress

I am building my own - custom - theme in WP.
In my `index.php`, I have many static contents ( Don't know how to convert them into dynamic fields in WP yet, but I will learn this later ).

The issue is that I want to display a number of posts in the homepage `2 posts` and below them a link to redirect the user to a `blog` page which displays the whole posts.

I searched a lot and I found a solution which is not doing what I want, it was about setting a static `front-page` and set the `blog` page as the `Posts page` under `settings` then `reading`.

After doing so, the whole static content - that was in my `index.php` doesn't appear on the `homepage` anymore and the `homepage` becomes an empty page and the whole content went to the `blog` page, which made me CRAZY!!

**All I want to do; is to keep my `static` content and `2 of my most recent posts` in the `homepage` and create a `blog` page which contains the whole posts.**

Hope to find a solution for this *Without Plugins*.

Answer (score 1):

Add This Snippet Code into your `front-page.php` or wherever you want to show **2** posts recently published.And Also a Blog Page Link to navigate the user to all blog posts..

```
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post',
                          'posts_per_page' => 2,
                          'orderby' => 'publish_date',
                          'order' => 'DESC'
                        )
                    );
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
the_title();
    the_excerpt();
        the_author();
        // add whatever you want
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
   echo 'See All Blog Posts Here : <a href='.site_url("blog").'>All Blog Posts</a>';
   else :
   esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts yet published.' );
   endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sajjadur for helping me out!

I did this and it works for me to display 2 posts in my `index` page.
Then, I created a page called `page-blog.php` and start the `posts loop` there, then created a page in my WP called `blog`.

Now, I can display 2 posts in my `index.php` but I can't display the whole posts in the `blog` page!
How can I display some content in the `blog` page!?

Comment: Don't your theme have any index.php or archive.php file?

Comment: It is. I have used this snippet in my `index.php` and it works fine.
Now, I just want to display the whole posts in the `blog` page, when I am trying to use the previous loop - which was working fine in `index.php` before - it shows no posts at all.

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: The `blog` page doesn't display any posts, the previous loop - that I was using before in my `index.php` - doesn't work there.

Comment: I think everything is working now as I needed.
Thanks for helping me Sajjadur and I will write a detailed answer to help others who might face this problem.

Comment: You are always Welcome Elharony

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a detailed answer to my problem to help anyone who might face the same problem, it will cover everything in steps for a WordPress newbie, like me! :D

As mentioned in my Question, my problem is that I want to display 2 posts in my `index.php` and make a separate `blog` page contains the whole posts.

**The Most Detailed Solution:**

1) Go to your `index.php` and use the normal posts loop:

```
<?php
    // The Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            //
            // Post Content here
            //
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

2) From WP Dashboard, go to `Settings` then `Reading` and change the `Blog pages show at most` value to 2 posts *Or whatever number of posts you want*.

Now, we've done the first step and show only a specific number of posts in our `index.php`, let's continue the steps to display the whole posts in our `blog` page.

3) Create a PHP Page called `page-blog.php`.

**Notice:** if you don't have a `page.php` you have to create it, for more information about how to create a custom PHP Page, I recommend @Adam's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress).

4) Go to your WP Dashboard and create a new page called `blog`.

5) In your `page-blog.php` you need to add this snippet:

```
// Posts Query
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged );
query_posts($args);

// The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            //
            // Post Content here
            //
        } // end while
} else {
    echo "Sorry, There is no posts to be displayed";
} // end if
?>
```

**Notice:** We used the same loop as we did before in `index.php`, only the new 2 lines of codes which above the loop is the new different thing here in our `page-blog.php` page

6) I set the `posts_per_page` to 6 because it is my `blog` page and I want to display more posts there. *Set its value to whatever number you want, it depends on you*

7) BOOM, it works and you did what you wanted, just like me!!

This problem seemed VERY COMPLICATED for me, but when I searched and read more information about this, I found that it is a VERY EASY to solve problem, and I hope this answer help you if you faced it!