# Wordpress php file inside plugin 403 error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin and I need to open new windows with some PHP code to display information from a database. The way I've gotten it to work so far was to add these pages to the submenu of the plugin, but these files shouldn't be accessible this way.

I'm aware of the include() function; however, I've only gotten it to work in the root of my installation, not actually INSIDE the plugin. Whenever I try to put myphp.php into the intended folder inside the plugin folder, I get a 403 error.

I've tried this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800534/19996081) solution which was the closest to my issue I could find, but it doesn't change anything.

Here's my plugin page which links to myphp.php:

```
include(site_url("/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/myphp.php")); 
// some HTML...

<a href="<?php echo site_url("/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/myphp.php"); ?>" target="blank">click</a>
```

And myphp.php:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../../wp-config.php');
$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();
$wp->send_headers();

// content goes here...

?>
```

I tried to put the file in different locations, it worked ONLY when myphp.php was in the same folder (root) as wp-config. tried different paths to reach wp-config (hardcoded, $_SERVER) none worked.

Comment: If you don't want the pages to appear in the menu, it might just be easiest to register a single page and then conditionally show things using the query string

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to tell what you actually want to achieve here. _"gotten it to work so far was to add these pages to the submenu of the plugin, but these files shouldn't be accessible this way"_ - so what else do you actually want then?

Comment: `include(site_url("/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/myphp.php"));` - `site_url` should result in an absolute URL, so you would not be including the actual PHP code (so that it will execute in the context of the script that _does_ the include), but only the _output_ of that script, requested via HTTP(S). That usually doesn't make the most sense to begin with ...

Comment: @CBroe I want to link to a new php-file (that isn't a WP page or post) from inside my plugin WITHOUT making this page accessible from the menu. Sorry if this doesn't make a lot of sense, i'm pretty new at this.

Comment: PHP files inside of a plugin should rather not be requested directly from the frontend, that is pretty much against "WP philosophy". You could create a custom page template in your plugin, and then assign that to an actual page. Or you could implement a shortcode to render the data, and then put that shortcode into the content of an actual page/post.

Answer (score 0):

1. in admin area when **user is logged in**, create a nonce:

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce('whatever_nonce_name');
```

2. Make page url like so:

```
$pageUrl = site_url("/wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/myphp.php") . "?nonce={$nonce}"
```

it's best to use a dynamic url there and not hardcode the name of your plugin, but that's another topic.

3. Add HTML link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $pageUrl; ?>" target="blank">click</a>
```

4. Inside your php file do something like this:

```
<?php
    require_once "../../../../wp-load.php";

    if ( ! isset($_GET['nonce']) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_GET['nonce'], 'whatever_nonce_name')) {
        exit( __('Access denied.') );
    }

    // rest of the code here.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but I still get a 403 error.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct nonce name when you check in step 4.
The nonce name should be the same name you used when you create the nonce in step 1.

Answer (score -2):

Make front end page and allow user to access it with password or something. Wont show page in menu or submenu